# HTML making menu expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make "javascript project" and "CGI project" to slide toggle when I click the "project" button. However, I don't quite understand why only the CGI project button toggle when I click, and the javascript project button remains unchange?

I am trying to use Jquery to achieve the slide toggle effect, but it seems only the CGI project react, but both buttons have the same exact HTML code and css. What makes the difference??

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        *{box-sizing: border-box}
        body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
        
        /* Style the tab */
        div.tab {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 250px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
        div.tab button {
            font-size: 18px;
            display: block;
            background-color: inherit;
            color: black;
            padding: 22px 16px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            text-align: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        
        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
        div.tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
        div.tab button.active {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        
        .projectList {
            display: none;
        }
        
        /* Style the tab content */
        .tabContent {
            float: left;
            padding: 0px 12px;
            width: 70%;       
            height: 500px;
        }
        
        li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'About Myself')" id="defaultOpen">About Myself</button>
            <button class="tabLinks" id="projects">Projects
                <li id="java"><button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'javascript project')">Javascript project</button></li>
                <li id="cgi"><button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'cgi project')">CGI project</button></li>
            </button>
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
        </div>
     
        <div id="About Myself", class="tabContent">
            <h3>About Myself</h3>
            <p>This is my information section</p>
        </div>
    
        <div id="Contact", class="tabContent">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <p>This it contact section</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="javascript project", class="tabContent">
            <h3>Javascript Project</h3>
            <p>This is javascript project section</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="cgi project", class="tabContent">
            <h3>CGI project</h3>
            <p>This is the CGI project section</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script>
        function openInfo(evt, diplayInfo) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            
            // Get all elements with class="tabContent" and hide them
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            
            // Get all elements with class="tabLinks" and remove the class "active"
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabLinks");
            for(i=0; i<tablinks.length; i++){
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            
            // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
            document.getElementById(diplayInfo).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#projects").on("click", function(){
                $("#java").slideToggle(500);
                $("#cgi").slideToggle(500);
            });
        });
        
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<div>` IDs have spaces in them, which is invalid markup. Your jQuery is probably getting confused as a result. Please consider hyphens or underscores for double-barrel IDs, and switching `#project` to the class `.project` :)

Comment: I really suggest you  to first rewrite your HTML markup for the projects button, you are using `<li> ` without any `<ul>` and also placing button inside another button which are not good practice way of markup if they are not error. the other thing I suggest is keep using jQuery if you added it to your script, it helps the understanding and reading the code rather than use native JavaScript and jQuery randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only look for a fix for your code you can replace project button with this markup:

```
<button class="tabLinks" id="projects">Projects</button>
<div id="projects-list">
    <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'javascript project')">Javascript project</button>
    <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'cgi project')">CGI project</button>
</div>
```

and then change the jQuery toggle slide to :

```
$("#projects").on("click", function(){
    $("#projects-list").slideToggle(500); 
});
```

---

But i really suggest to take a look at the below solution which might help you as well.

As far as I understood nowadays such menus will be generated by HTML list element and for your case can be something like this :

```
<nav  class="side-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a>
      <ul class="projects-list">
        <li><a href="#javascript-projects">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cgi-projects">CGI</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact me</a></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and then jQuery ( JS ) part can be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var projectsList = $('ul.projects-list');
    $('nav').on('click','a',function(){         // binds event on each link in nav container (uses event delegate)
       var contentId = $(this).attr('href');    // gets content id based on link href attribute
       if(contentId==='#projects'){             // if clicked item is projects  
          projectsList.slideToggle(300);        // then toggle projects list
       } else {                                 // else  
          $('.tabContent').fadeOut(0);          // fadeout all contents
          $(contentId).fadeIn(300);             // and fade in content of clicked link
       }
   });
});
```

for the CSS and see it in action I suggest you to check it here please : https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/zzXPaK

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me, your answer is great. I still have a little confusion, why you use 'a' instead of 'button'? Another question, when you write ul.projects-list, does 'projects-list' has to be inside the tag <ul>, and it won't work if it is inside other tag such as <li>?

Comment: glad to hear that, well for the 'a' instead of button part, I think it makes more sense as they are still a link rather than a button, also they change the URL using hashtag which gives also more sense to users when using this app, another reason should be that whoever see your code he or she expects those elements as a link not a button.
for the 'projects-list', actually any container block like div or p or.... can be instead of 'ul' as long as it has the class, but as said in my answer it does make more sense to wrap nav items as list element, therefore I suggested a 'ul' as the container.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="tabLinks" id="projects">Projects</button>
    <ul>
        <li id="java">
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'javascript project')">Javascript project</button>
        </li>
        <li id="cgi">
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'cgi project')">CGI project</button>
        </li>
    <ul>
```